# Looking for a php library to generate vector graphics as pdf or svg files

Tags: php, pdf, svg

Basically i want a library for PHP that i can use to generate vector based graphic files like svg or pdf. it need to be able to output path and not pixel based results.

for example i want it to use like

generate_circle($radius)

etc

Answer (score 2):

[PHP bindings for cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/cairo-php/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard to generate svg from php, here are some [examples](http://wiki.svg.org/index.php/SVG_and_PHP).

If you really want a library, there are probably many different options, [SVGGraph](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php) and the ones pointed out [here](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/37004) for example.

Google will help you find others I'm sure :)